# Select rowst where ID is on list and meet 2 other requirement, probably subquery in Teradata SQL?

Tags: sql, subquery, teradata, where-clause, teradatasql

I have table in Teradata SQL like below:

```
ID   | col1 | col2
-------------------
111  | A  | 54
222  | B  | 8
333  | C  | 17
444  | B  | 44
555  | A  | 1
```

And I have list of ID of clients:

```
myList = ['111', '222', '333']
```

And I need to select ID of clients from table which are on myList and meet requirements:

1. In col1 value is "A" or "B"
2. In col2 value is bigger than 10 (>10)

So as a result I need like below:

```
ID   | col1 | col2
--------------------
111  | A    | 54
```

Because ID = 111 and is on `myList`, col1 is "A" or "B" and in col2 is value bigger than 10.

How can I do that in Teradata SQL ? Probably in subquery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a subquery.
All conditions can be combined with the `AND` operator in the `WHERE` clause of a simple `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename
WHERE ID IN ('111', '222', '333')
  AND col1 IN ('A', 'B')
  AND col2 > 10
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try an aggregation approach here:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE ID IN ('111', '222', '333') AND
      ID IN (SELECT ID
             FROM yourTable
             GROUP BY ID
             HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN col1 NOT IN ('A', 'B') THEN 1 END) = 0 AND
                    COUNT(CASE WHEN col2 > 10 THEN 1 END) > 0);
```

The `WHERE` clause restricts `ID` values to your client list.  The two conditions in the `HAVING` clause check for the restrictions on the two other columns.